# Netcore, JSON Parameter always null

Tags: javascript, c#, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what changed.
I'm trying send JSON parameters to an mvc controller in netcore 1.1

MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test1(DepartmentDTO departmentDto, int testId)
{
    return Json(departmentDto);
}
public partial class DepartmentDTO
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

Javascript POST:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/Department/Test1",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "departmentDto": { "DepartmentID": 1, "Description": "TEST" },
        "testId": 1
    }),
};
var promise = $http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {
    if (response.data.departmentID == 0) {
        alert("Wrong")
    }
    return response.data
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    return { success: false, message: response.data };
});
```

All parameters are always null: departmentDto & testId
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: All parameters are always null.

Comment: All parameters to *what*?

Comment: try adding `[FromBody]` in the parameters list

Comment: It does not work either:

public JsonResult Test1([FromBody] DepartmentDTO departmentDto, [FromBody] int testId)

Only the field DepartmentID has value. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[FromBody]` can only be used once. The Body stream is forward only.

Suggestion:

```
[Route("Department")]
public class DepartmentController : Controller 
{
    [HttpPost("Test1/{testId:int}")] // Matches POST Department/Test1/1
    public IActionResult Test1([FromRoute] int testId, [FromBody] DepartmentDTO departmentDto)
    {
        return Json(departmentDto);
    }
}
```

And modify request

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/Department/Test1/1",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ "DepartmentID": 1, "Description": "TEST" }),
};
```

Either that or create a new object model that matches what was stringified from the client and have that as the single action parameter tagged with `[FromBody]`